# Is it safe to temporarily delete hibernation and paging files?

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, system-file

Would it be safe to temporarily delete the following files from C:\

> hiberfi.sys
>   pagefile.sys
>   swapfile.sys

in order to backup the Operating System? Would the OS re-generate them later on? When?

Comment: What do you mean by **temporarily**, will you restore(/copy back) them after deleting?

Comment: Assuming the system will restore it later on.

Comment: presumably you're not trying to do this on the drive you're currently booted from?

Comment: …. Doesn't your backup software have an option to exclude some files?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that from the currently booted drive. @grawity: I have to check this if the backup software silently exclude those files. I am using Paragon's Backup and Recovery [tool](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/).

Comment: I exclude those files when I backup using Acronis, It could cause boot problems after restoring the image but Windows recovery environment repairs it if you run a startup repair.

Comment: I just checked It also backups it up by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that Paragon's Backup and Recovery tool doesn't include these files in actual backups. Only the names of the files however appear in explorer because they are present in Master File table back up partition (which is not the actual data on disk).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that on a virtual machine and, if you are not planning on backuping a hibernated system, you are good to go.